# Can I usefully add a page break to a web page?

Tags: html, css, page-break

The CSS [page-break-after](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_print_pageba.asp) attribute looks like what I want.  Is it?  This is an intranet application for Firefox users, so browser compatibility is not a large concern.

Here's the background.  I have a web application that generates medical forms.  Right now the users click on individual forms and print out the result on at a time.  They want a single button that will let them print all the necessary forms at once.  The HTML forms are templated in such a way that I can concatenate them together, the problem is the page break.  I need to put a page break between forms so they paginate properly when printed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to do this in a non-hackish way, it seems. However, I did get some good results in Firefox using the following:

```
div.page {page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-before: always;}
```

If I remember correctly, 'page-break-inside' is what would have been ideal, but didn't completely work in FF. 'page-break-before' worked nicely for me. Just make sure you don't apply it to the very first div (or whatever element you use); otherwise, the first page to be printed will be blank.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will do what you want.  Personally I've always used [page-break-before](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_print_pagebb.asp), but it's 6 of one, 1/2 dozen of the other.